# Bintray Debian Repository for several distribuitions

Tags: debian, bintray

Using OSS Bintray:
When trying to upload a deb file for a specific distro, the file uploaded to "dists/all" and NOT to dists/xenial.
Here are my commands:
create a repo:

```
curl -uUSER:API_KEY https://api.bintray.com/repos/myorg/Debian -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Debian","type":"debian","default_debian_architecture":"amd64","default_debian_distribution":"all","default_debian_component":"main","private":false,"desc":"This repo for our poc","business_unit":"businessUnit1","labels":["label1","label2"],"gpg_sign_metadata":false,"gpg_sign_files":false,"gpg_use_owner_key":false}' -v
```

Then I created a Package "Test" by the UI and uploaded a debian file into the "Test":

```
curl -T file_0.9.8_amd64.deb -uUSER:API_KEY https://api.bintray.com/content/myorg/Debian/Test/0.9.8/file_0.9.8_amd64.deb;deb_distribution=xenial;deb_component=main;deb_architecture=amd64
```

Is there a way to use one repo for all distros (xenial/bionic) and all architectures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have one repository for all your Debian distribution and architecture.
You need to submit the distribution and architecture in the [upload debian](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_debian_upload) command with *comma-separated values*. It should look like so:

```
curl -T your_file.deb -u user:api_key "https://api.bintray.com/content/:subject/:repo/:package/:version/:file_path;deb_distribution=xenial,bionic;deb_component=main;deb_architecture=amd64"
```

Comment: This is what I did. you can see my command in the original question: deb_distribution=xenial. However, the file added to the dists/all and not under the 'xenial' as expected.

Comment: link to the repository?

Comment: https://bintray.com/mycoolorg/Debian

note, i didnt publish the file yet

Comment: no, there are no quotation marks in the "Set me up". any way, when i try now with or without them, i got an error: "Failed to connect to api.bintray.com port 443: Timed out".  Maybe some network issues....

Comment: With quotation marks it should work, see my example. You need to use quotation marks with curl when you are using special characters.

Comment: After fixing a network, I tried now with them, same result. Maybe after publishing it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177104/discussion-between-dima-kreisserman-and-royg).